# how to find information on clojure libraries

Tags: clojure

For example, I am trying to find information on the latest version of core.async library. I tried searching at https://clojars.org/ , and I got 82 hits with items like **org.clojars.trptcolin/core.async** and **org.dunaj/core.async**

However, when I goto the github for clojure at https://github.com/clojure I get 2 hits only, and the entry at https://github.com/clojure/core.async points to **org.clojure/core.async**

So what is the recommended method of finding out a library? (1) to goto github/clojure and search, or (2) goto clojars.org and search?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Clojure-toolbox](http://www.clojure-toolbox.com/) is an excellent index of useful Clojure libraries.

If you know the name of the library you want, but are not sure about the version,
[lein-ancient](https://github.com/xsc/lein-ancient) is fantastic! Simply add it to your profile and then you can type `lein ancient upgrade` and it will rewrite your project with the latest version.

Comment: Thanks for the toolbox link, thats great. Regarding the ancient link, isnt an auto-upgrade a risk, if things are not backward compatible?

Comment: I always use `lein ancient` and update libraries one by one, testing them along the way, reading changelogs etc.

Comment: lein ancient runs all your tests automatically and will only update the project file if they all pass. (you can override this behavior, but it is on by default).

Comment: Nice suggestion and +1 for the link

Answer (score 1):

I usually just check the appropriate github page to see what the most current version is, that can be difficult though as you mentioned.

An easier way might be to just include whatever version you can find and then use the [lein ancient](https://github.com/xsc/lein-ancient) plugin to tell you what the most recent version is.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would start at *the* official source: http://clojure.org/api/api.  Then follow the advice in the other answers if needed.  For example, on http://clojure.github.io/core.async/, there's a link to the github page, so it's easy to check the github page, as Bill suggested.  I'm not sure how you could get more up to date information than that.

Answer (score 0):

Not saying it is super straightforward. But this should usually work:

- Go to [Clojars](https://clojars.org/)
- Search `core.async`
- Click on eg. [org.dunaj/core.async](https://clojars.org/org.dunaj/core.async)
- Click its [GitHub link](https://github.com/dunaj-project/core.async)
- Notice *"forked from clojure/core.async"* below the page title.
- Click [it](https://github.com/clojure/core.async).
- Scroll down to find Leiningen info `[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]`.
- Confirm that it matched the repo.

Being able to publish personal/unofficial releases are useful. And IMO it's worth the (temporary) confusion.